# Reputation notification says “+-49” with plus and minus, instead of either “+49” or “-49”

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

I logged in today and saw what first appeared to be a +49 rep gain:

[image]

Upon further inspection you can see it actually says "+-49". Shouldn't that be "-49". And after doing the math, I lost 50 rep on the removed user and one in a downvote I made earlier, so shouldn't it be "-51"?

I don't remember what my rep was before the removed user, so I don't know by how much my rep actually changed.

EDIT:
I just checked the "Reputation" tab in my user profile (which I failed to do earlier) and it only has the downvote -1 rep. No mention of the removed user stuff. So I guess the -50 didn't get enforced??

Comment: This looks like a bug to me as well, it shouldn't be +-, and also, I thought that negative rep simply didn't show in the indicator? Odd.

Comment: Yes, it is odd. It doesn't say who the user(s) were or what questions were involved. I believe I did have a serial upvoter years ago - maybe it was that user?

Comment: Can’t reproduce it right now. Can any of you upvote some of my answers, so I can see the bug, too? 

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SE: [Negative reputation shows as +-1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329827/289905).

Comment: I guess this is site-wide. Should I delete this post?

Comment: Idk about delete, but it could probably be closed.

Comment: That post was asked 12 mins ago. Maybe this bug just came in the recent build?

Comment: I have the same issue, with +-2 rep.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking the same question about the same bug on multiple metas. People are going to do it anyway. As long as this one is here, others can be closed as a duplicate. Plus, this one was posted first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fixed per [Positive AND Negative reputation show as +-1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329827/positive-and-negative-reputation-show-as-1/329836#329836):

> I had to tweak the code to pass a number around instead of a string, and I mistakenly replaced `rep.IsNullOrEmpty()` with `rep == 0` instead of `rep <= 0`.